# Making An Energy Momentum Plot For A Rashba Model (Using Discretization)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, momentum, eigenvalue, discrete

I want to make a plot of the Energy versus the Momentum of the Rashba model, using discrete matrices. First Ill show how I did this for the free particle. Subsequently I will show what goes wrong for the Rashba model, where, to make things easy, I've set the momentum operator to $P=(1,0,0)$.

Discretization procedure:

$x=n \cdot a$, where $n$ runs from $-N, N+1, ...,N$ and $a$ is the discretization step.
$\psi(x)=\psi(x_{n})=\psi_{n}$.Turning differentials into difference equations, $\nabla^2 = \frac{U_{n+1}+U_{n-1}-2U_{n}}{a^2}$.
We add boundary conditions: $\psi_{N+1}=\psi_{-N}$. We add spin structure to the Hamiltonian.

Discrete one dimensional momentum operator (for a small system):

\begin{equation}
P_{x} \psi =- i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x)=-i\hbar \frac{\psi_{n+1}-\psi_{n-1}}{2a}=-\frac{i\hbar}{2a}\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&-1\\-1&0&1&0\\0&-1&0&1\\1&0&-1&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \psi_{1}\\\psi_{2}\\\psi_{3}\\\psi_{4}\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Free particle Hamiltonian continuous:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}=\frac{\hbar^2 \nabla^2}{2m}.
\end{equation}

Then discretized (written as the Schodinger equation):
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}_{free} \psi(x)\rightarrow \mathcal{H}^{discrete}_{free} \psi_{n}= \begin{pmatrix} 2J&0&-J&0\\  0&2J&0&-J\\-J&0&2J&0\\0&-J&0&2J\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\psi_{1,+}\\\psi_{1, -}\\ \psi_{2, +}\\\psi_{2, -} \end{pmatrix}=\epsilon \begin{pmatrix}\psi_{1, +}\\ \psi_{1, -}\\\psi_{2, +}\\\psi_{2, -} \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $J$ is the hopping parameter defined as $J=\frac{\hbar^2}{2ma^2}$.

We then check if the Hamiltonian commutes with the momentum operator(sharing their eigenstates), and they do commute. We want a plot of the Energy of the system(the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian) versus the corresponding momentum. We explicitly link the two as follows:
\begin{equation}
\epsilon= \frac{\langle p|\mathcal{H}_{free}|p\rangle}{\langle p|p\rangle},
\end{equation}
where $|p\rangle$ are the eigenstates of the momentum operator: $P|p\rangle=p|p\rangle$. Now we can make a plot: on the $y$-axis $\epsilon$ and on the $x$-axis the eigenvalues of the momentum operator $p$. Setting all parameters to 1, size of the matrices $N=100$, we find:

[image]

Then the Rashba Model with $P = (1,0,0)$:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}_{free}+\mathcal{H}_{R}= \frac{-\hbar^2\nabla^2}{2m}-\frac{\alpha_{R}}{\hbar}(\tau\times p)\cdot\hat{z}= \frac{-\hbar^2\nabla^2}{2m}-\frac{\alpha_{R}}{\hbar}(-\tau_{y} P_{x}),
\end{equation}
where $\tau$ are the Pauli matrices. Discretized in matrix form (small system $N=4$):
\begin{equation}
(\mathcal{H}_{free}+\mathcal{H}_{Px=1}) \psi_{n}= 
 \begin{pmatrix} 2J&-\frac{i\alpha_{R}}{\hbar}&-J&0\\
\frac{i\alpha_{R}}{\hbar}&2J&0&-J\\
-J&0&2J&-\frac{i\alpha_{R}}{\hbar}\\
0&-J&\frac{i\alpha_{R}}{\hbar}&2J\\
 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \psi_{1,+}\\\psi_{1,-}\\\psi_{2,+}\\\psi_{2,-}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

We go through the same procedure: checking if the matrix commutes with the Momentum operator. It doesn't, so we need to give spin structure to the momentum operator. This means:
\begin{equation}
P_{x} \psi = -\frac{i\hbar}{2a}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \psi_{1}\\\psi_{2}\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow 
-\frac{i\hbar}{2a}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\-1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \psi_{1,+}\\\psi_{1,-}\\\psi_{2,+}\\\psi_{2,-}\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Then we explicitly link energy to momentum and we again plot the result:

[image]

This obviously doesn't make sense. Does anyone know what's wrong here?
What could be the problem is that we should turn the story around, since for the Rashba case the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian and the momentum operator are not 1:1. So we should try:
\begin{equation}
p= \frac{\langle\psi|\hat{P}|\psi\rangle}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle}
\end{equation}
where $|\psi\rangle$ are the eigenstates of the Rashba Hamiltonian. However when I plot the result, it again gives chaos. I can give Mathematica code if needed. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if you mistyped it, but the equation for the Rashba term is incorrect. Since it's the $z$-component of the cross-product, it should be ($T_{x}P{y}-P_{x}T_{y}$).